# How to create two column layout with separate scroll bar each column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, layout

I am relatively new to UI Development. currently I'm trying to create a two column layout web page as [below,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hldbg.png)

1. both side bav bar and main panel should stay in display width.
2. if the content is overflow then I should get a separate scrollbar for each.
3. The scroll bar should scroll content in particular divs. (mostly like [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp))

I tried with overflow css property for each divs but seems I should set a static height to get scroll bar. is there any other way to archive this regardless of static width and height?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe, this will provide you with an idea. Hope it helps.

```css
#wrapper{
  width:100%;
  background:gray;
  height:100vh;
  display:flex;
}
#col-1{
  width:20%;
  height:100vh;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  background:blue;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
#col-2{
  width:80%;
  height:100vh;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="col-1">
    RANDOMTEXTRANDOMTEXTRANDOMTEXTRANDOMTEXTRANDOMTEXTRANDOMTEXTRANDOMTEXTRANDOMTEXTRANDOMTEXTRANDOMTEXTRANDOMTEXTRANDOMTEXTRANDOMTEXTRANDOMTEXTRANDOMTEXTRANDOMTEXTRANDOMTEXTRANDOMTEXTRANDOMTEXTRANDOMTEXTRANDOMTEXTRANDOMTEXTRANDOMTEXTRANDOMTEXTRANDOMTEXTRANDOMTEXTRANDOMTEXTRANDOMTEXTRANDOMTEXTRANDOMTEXTRANDOMTEXTRANDOMTEXTRANDOMTEXTRANDOMTEXTRANDOMTEXTRANDOMTEXT
  </div>
  <div id="col-2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: No problem, rate it up or mark it if it helped. Cheers

Comment: i wish i could but due to some stackoverflow policy i'm not able to upvote any answers :(

Comment: Oh, alright I think its maybe due to the reputation since I think you might have just started using SO. But I think you might be able to mark the answer correct if you found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `height` (or `width`) of this two columns and `overflow-y` of columns (`auto` - will show scroll only when needed or `scroll` - will show scrollbar always)

```css
.column {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class='column'>
  first column<br>
  first column<br>
  first column<br>
  first column<br>
  first column<br>
  first column<br>
  first column<br>
  first column<br>
  first column<br>
  first column<br>
  first column<br>
</div>
<div class='column'>
  second column<br>
  second column
</div>
```

Comment: It's obvious, that's only quick example

Answer (score 0):

Set the height & width in `%`.Also set `overflow-y:auto` which will show the scrollbar if the content overflows the height of the container

```css
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

.leftMenu {
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%
}

.rightMenu {
  width: 55%;
  height: 100%
}

.cc {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow-y: auto
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="leftMenu cc">
    Salim is a small boy, but his voice is commanding. His favorite song once floated above the paddy fields of Myanmar’s Rakhine state, heard only by a few grazing cattle and the heavens. Composed in October last year in a melodic dialect similar to Bengali,
    the words now fall on the rapt ears of children in the world’s largest refugee camp, reminding them why they are there.
  </div>
  <div class="rightMenu cc">
    The sight of barefoot masses arriving on the shore can only be described as biblical. Well over 622,000 Rohingya have endured the dangerous passage from their homes in Rakhine to the relative safety of Cox’s Bazar, a district of eastern Bangladesh,
    over the past three months — the fastest refugee movement
  </div>
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with javascript. This is accomplished by using HTML and CSS. If you want seperate scrollbars - use a fixed `height` (or `max-height`) and `overflow-y: auto;` I made an example for you below. For the second column we use a calculated width `calc(100% - 200px)`. Here you use the total width of the parent (wrapper) minus the pixel width of the first column.

```css
.wrapper{
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

.left{
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: blue;
}
.right{
  float: left;
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
      <li>6</li>
      <li>7</li>
      <li>8</li>
      <li>9</li>
      <li>10</li>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
      <li>6</li>
      <li>7</li>
      <li>8</li>
      <li>9</li>
      <li>10</li>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
      <li>6</li>
      <li>7</li>
      <li>8</li>
      <li>9</li>
      <li>10</li>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
      <li>6</li>
      <li>7</li>
      <li>8</li>
      <li>9</li>
      <li>10</li> 
     </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec nec sem cursus, rhoncus risus non, finibus nulla. Aliquam pellentesque mi ut aliquet porta. Ut dictum convallis leo, vitae posuere nisi ullamcorper sit amet. Phasellus mi felis, cursus in faucibus et, vestibulum sed neque. Quisque vestibulum orci vel dui dignissim mollis. Ut commodo dignissim dui, ac facilisis nunc pellentesque id. Vestibulum vitae sagittis nisi, in tincidunt erat. Nullam dignissim, urna id dignissim pretium, purus magna lacinia ligula, quis ornare urna sem vitae ipsum. Maecenas viverra ipsum quis ante aliquet eleifend. Mauris mollis neque ornare magna condimentum molestie. Ut varius, sapien et posuere ullamcorper, nunc nisl scelerisque orci, vel pellentesque ex tortor quis dolor. Morbi vehicula nisl sapien, nec porta nisl ullamcorper eu.

Pellentesque eu ultrices massa. Nullam tristique lorem et ante elementum dignissim. Sed rutrum, justo vehicula tristique imperdiet, diam purus convallis ante, nec suscipit nisi augue at urna. Vestibulum ut sollicitudin risus. Nullam luctus fermentum ex non convallis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Praesent ultricies a nulla ac ornare. Cras congue sagittis risus ac efficitur. Maecenas eleifend dapibus tincidunt.

Nam id ornare justo. Donec tempor libero ac est sollicitudin sodales. Nunc efficitur nulla at sodales sollicitudin. Nulla facilisi. Nulla tincidunt, nunc et ultrices mollis, enim risus auctor orci, eu posuere magna dolor fringilla ante. Suspendisse imperdiet fringilla mauris vitae pellentesque. Quisque eget feugiat nunc. Mauris ullamcorper augue eget tincidunt ornare. Ut eu ex ut dui maximus dignissim. Fusce condimentum feugiat nibh, ut accumsan tellus mattis eu. Donec vitae magna eget arcu tempus sagittis nec eget felis. Aenean nunc turpis, rhoncus ac pharetra sed, feugiat eget felis.

Morbi vitae augue pretium, dignissim odio at, consequat dolor. Maecenas a elit sit amet odio ultricies gravida. Fusce velit orci, cursus et sagittis ac, convallis eu nisi. Etiam ornare id sapien sed malesuada. Nullam quis dictum metus. Nulla vehicula tortor felis, id vestibulum lacus placerat quis. Etiam vel pretium orci. Quisque ut metus id urna tincidunt tempus. Quisque sit amet nisl sem.

Nunc iaculis pretium lobortis. Phasellus pretium id elit a tempor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Sed id turpis at eros semper egestas. Mauris enim velit, ullamcorper non gravida a, laoreet eu nisi. Pellentesque congue velit tellus, non posuere massa pulvinar ac. Nullam vel nunc et purus tempus congue. Suspendisse dolor dui, porttitor a interdum quis, aliquam at eros. Donec facilisis, mauris sed ultrices dictum, odio eros consequat nunc, vitae vestibulum turpis mauris in felis. Vivamus non augue ut urna tempus facilisis. Aliquam sit amet velit quis turpis aliquet faucibus nec aliquam elit. Proin iaculis mollis erat sed tincidunt.
  </div>
</div>
```